# Any chance anyone looking into evolutionary algorithms for Blender?

Tags: scripting

Something similar to Galapagos plugin in Grasshopper shown in link below:
https://yazdanistudioresearch.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/evolutionary-form-finding-with-grasshopper-galapagoes/

Comment: do you test https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65610/how-would-one-go-about-creating-a-genetic-algorithm-and-or-neural-network-for-bl ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Comment: The galapagos is just an example plugin from grasshopper showcasing the possibilities that blender can have. Anyway, I think the programming approach could be more direct and open solution :)

Comment: Manage to find a video to reproduce image with genetic algorithm:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iV-hah6xs2A

Comment: My objective is to test K-d tree on spatial planning with Blender 2.80.

Answer (score 1):

some good codes (K-d tree) and similar topic found, showcasing computational Blender possible through python or programming approach :)

[How would one go about creating a genetic algorithm and/or neural network for blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65610/how-would-one-go-about-creating-a-genetic-algorithm-and-or-neural-network-for-bl)

https://www.blender.org/conference/2017/presentations/352

https://salzis.wordpress.com/2014/06/28/kd-tree-and-nearest-neighbor-nn-search-2d-case/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qc9Mp4TdS2k (K-d Tree for animation! Can it be spatial planning!?)

Comment: Three detail videos explained with python codes in K-d tree:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLguYJK7ydFE7R7KqRRVXw23kOrn6jiwqi

Answer (score 0):

I suppose someone had done it in blender splitting the cube with a K-d tree algorithms shown in the animation here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHkaapcPyp0
Here is another good idea of what can be done through Blender but in 3D form by just splitting the cubes.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1wvssK-B9U