# Can't install pip due to PermissionError on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, installation

New to Blender. Experienced with Python 2.7.

I am trying to install pip in my Blender Python implementation. I am attempting to do this by following the instructions in [How to use PIP with Blender's bundled Python? - Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56013/51056), which links to [Install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

I followed those instructions, and it seemed to be going well, but I got a PermissionError. I switched from doing it cmd.exe to PowerShell, but encountered the same problem.

### Question

**What do I need to do to get past the PermissionError?**

Here is the full output from the command execution, including the exception message:

```
PS C:\Users\Paul Schrum> cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\lib"
PS C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\lib> ..\bin\python D:\SourceModules\get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-38.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\PAULSC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Users\PAULSC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
  File "C:\Users\PAULSC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Users\PAULSC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files

isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Users\PAULSC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Users\PAULSC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "C:\Users\PAULSC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp185kt8q9\pip.zip\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\lib\os.py", line 241, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.79\\python\\Lib\\site
```

-packages\pip'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Blender, but about an operating system issue...

Comment: were you running the cmd with administrator rights?

Comment: m.arito, can you give me a chance. How am I supposed to know it is an os issue? It has only happened to me while working with Blender. Voting to close it is saying I didn't understand the answer to my question well enough before I asked it.

Comment: David, I thought I was, but I was mistaken at the time.  My best solution (see my own answer, below) turned out to be to reinstall Blender at a different location. I needed it out of C:\Program Files\ anyway for other reasons. Doing this eliminated the administrator privileges issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7, I go to the start menu, type `cmd`, when cmd.exe pops up, I right-click that and choose 'Run as administrator'. This solves the permission errors. Here's a guide for how to do it on Windows 8.1, see [method 1](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Away from this forum, a colleague suggested I reinstall Blender to a location other than C:\Program Files.

I tried his suggestion, and it works fine.

Problem resolved.