# How to write my add-on so that when installed it also installs dependencies (let's say: scipy or numpy-quaternion)?

Tags: add-on

How to write my add-on so that when installed it also installs dependencies (let's say: scipy or numpy-quaternion)?

Does blender understand setuptools (setup.py)?

Thanks,

*Note: I'm using blender 2.8*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ran into the same issue and received [helpful responses](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/can-3rd-party-modules-ex-scipy-be-installed-when-an-add-on-is-installed/9709) on devtalk. There's also [another post that was helpful when installing  pip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139718/install-pip-and-packages-from-within-blender-os-independently) for 2.81.

**2.81**

```
import subprocess
import bpy

py_exec = bpy.app.binary_path_python
# ensure pip is installed & update
subprocess.call([str(py_exec), "-m", "ensurepip", "--user"])
subprocess.call([str(py_exec), "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"])
# install dependencies using pip
# dependencies such as 'numpy' could be added to the end of this command's list
subprocess.call([str(py_exec),"-m", "pip", "install", "--user", "scipy"])
```

**Modification for 3.6**

```
import sys

py_exec = sys.executable
```

**Warnings:**

- On Windows, Blender must be run in Administrator mode. Blender may need to restart before using the installed dependency.
- Installing dependencies requires an active internet connection

Comment: It is worth mentioning, for those pip installing dependencies that need to build, that the python sources need to be present in: PATH_TO_BLENDER/2.80/python/include/python3.7m/. Sources must match blender's python version and can be grabbed from: https://www.python.org/downloads/source/. Otherwise an exception is thrown during installation mentioning the missing Python.h

Comment: I don't know about older version, but to reach python executable in blender 2.83 you can use bpy.app.binary_path_python

Comment: In 3.3 binary_path_python is missing. Instead you can use
import sys
python_path = sys.executable

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to keep add-on and dependencies installation separate, i.e:

First install deps into Blender's python:

1. ensure Blender's python installation has pip: `path/to/blender/python -m ensurepip` and `path/to/blender/python -m pip install -U pip`
2. And pip install your dependencies: `pip install <whatever need be>`
3. If any of the deps needs to be built, as opposed to installed from wheels, you have to ensure that the python includes are present, otherwise you will get an error about missing Python.h.

And then install the add-on.

This is not an elegant solution though, having to tell your users to go through this process is not convenient.