# How to import SciPy in Blender?

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import the SciPy library inside Blender version 2.8 and I am having trouble. I can import SciPy outside of Blender.

On my system Blender's Python is installed at

```
 /snap/blender/34/2.81/python
```

I tried the following answers I found here :

- As suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149944/how-to-write-my-add-on-so-that-when-installed-it-also-installs-dependencies-let/153520#153520) I tried to install ensurepip inside Blenders Python.
- I tried to copy the system Python's SciPy folder to Blender's Python site-packages folder.

Both of the solutions are trying to change Blender's python folder -

```
/snap/blender/34/2.81/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

And when I try them, I get stuck with this error :

```
"Read-only file system"
```

Remounting the file system doesn't work either, I am wondering if this has something to do with the way Blender 2.8 is installed using snaps?

What can I try next to get SciPy inside Blender?

Comment: Firstly I don't use snap install of blender so anything to follow is speculative. Am assuming you cannot rename `/snap/blender/34/2.81/python` either.  Try `pip install scipy  --user` to install to a local user folder.    As long as the python version of pip matches that of blender, I've found this is perhaps the simplest approach, maybe barring venvs.  I have installed `matplotlib, scipy, bezier, aubio, gdal` and numerous others this way without issue.

Comment: You did not mention what OS you are using. You need to make sure Blender has permissions to write to whatever parts of the file system it has to write during this. On Windows this can be done running Blender as administrator. The code from your link works fine when I test it on Windows starting Blender with Run as administrator.

Comment: Oops meant to mention using `sudo`.  Personally I would avoid using `sudo pip install` for the local method. Making the 3rd party libraries available to all.  Also forgot to mention `plumbum` one of my faves.  If you can `sudo mv` (rename) the blender python folder, blender will pick up the matching system python instead.

Comment: Alternatively if you set up a virtual environment using your blender python (or matching system python) set the following environment variables https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#environment-variables  @RobertGützkow let's say "another" approach.

Comment: @batFINGER that would be even better, venvs are the cleanest approach in my opinion until the user packages dir for Blender is used (see [T71420](https://developer.blender.org/T71420)).

Comment: @batFINGER If I use the ```--user``` option the modules are installed under ```~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages```. Is there any way to tell Blender to use site-packages stored under that location?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc  its appended to  my sys.path by default in `site.py` or in cmake can't remember.... .  Building blender so quite likely this is not standard. Appending it to your sys.path will have the desired result.

Comment: @batFINGER I don't really understand what you mean with "appending it to my sys.path"...