# Install new Python modules from within Addon (without sudo/admin privileges)

Tags: python, scripting

I am working under Blender 2.90 installed by snap.

If I try to run

```
subprocess.check_call([bpy.app.binary_path_python, "-m", "ensurepip"])
```

or

```
import ensurepip
ensurepip.bootstrap()
```

from within my Addon, I get told, that the site-packages of my Blender's Python are read-only. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Is this one helping? [python - How to import SciPy in Blender? - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161894/how-to-import-scipy-in-blender)

Comment: @HikariTW That thread was definitely interesting. However using the mentioned ```--user``` option installs the packages under ```~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages```. Is there any way to tell Blender to use those site-packages additionally to those installed under ```/snap/blender/45/2.90/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages``` which is unfortunately read-only (otherwise I would have installed my modules there in the first place).

Comment: Which OS/build are you aiming for? I don't think modify snap install folder is a good idea. And if addon need to deal with various OS/condition, ensure pip is definitely not enough

Comment: I'm on KDE Neon but all I want is for Blender to recognize ```~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages````as a place to look for packages.

Comment: Not familiar with kde neon, if you know exactly where the packages are: `sys.path.append(R"~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")` might work?

Comment: What does the ```R``` accomplish?

Comment: stand for raw input without translating `\\`, it's python feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the help, I was able to piece together a fully automatic solution that works at least on my system (tests on other Linux and Windows machines planned). It looks something like this:

```
import bpy
import sys
import importlib
import subprocess

# Blender's Python executable
pybin = sys.executable

def add_user_site():
    # Locate users site-packages (writable)
    user_site = subprocess.check_output([pybin, "-m", "site", "--user-site"])
    user_site = user_site.decode("utf8").rstrip("\n")   # Convert to string and remove line-break
    # Add user packages to sys.path (if it exits)
    user_site_exists = user_site is not None
    if user_site not in sys.path and user_site_exists:
        sys.path.append(user_site)
    return user_site_exists

def enable_pip():
    if importlib.util.find_spec("pip") is None:
        subprocess.check_call([pybin, "-m", "ensurepip", "--user"])
        subprocess.check_call([pybin, "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip", "--user"])
    
def install_module(module : str):
    if importlib.util.find_spec(module) is None:
        subprocess.check_call([pybin, "-m", "pip", "install", module, "--user"])

user_site_added = add_user_site()
enable_pip()
# All the modules you need, that don't come shipped with Blender
modules = ["module1", "module2", ...] 
for module in modules:
    install_module(module)
# If there was no user-site before...
if not user_site_added:
    add_user_site()
```

Comment: Please note that automatic loading of user site-packages was intentionally disabled, see [T76993](https://developer.blender.org/T76993). Manually appending to `sys.path` works, but there may be a different preferred approach in the future if progress is made on [T71420](https://developer.blender.org/T71420). Until then this approach is a viable alternative.

Comment: I'll be more than happy to drop this Frankenstein of a workaround as soon as Blender offers a more elegant solution :D

Answer (score 1):

The paths available in Blender 3.x include `/home/my-user/.config/blender/3.3/scripts/addons/modules` which is writable. It is possible to install your Python packages in this directory directly. For example:

```
pip install --target=$HOME/.config/blender/3.3/scripts/addons/modules/ my_package
```

Or on Windows:

```
pip install --target=%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.5\scripts\addons\modules my_package
```

Comment: That's `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.5\scripts\addons\modules` in Windows. One can also simply copy the module directories to the directory, from wherever they get install with system Python like maybe `%appdata%\Python\Python310\site-packages`