# Installing Python dependencies on Mac

Tags: python

I'm using MacOS Catalina and I following this question to install `scipy` with my addon: [How to write my add-on so that when installed it also installs dependencies (let's say: scipy or numpy-quaternion)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149944/how-to-write-my-add-on-so-that-when-installed-it-also-installs-dependencies-let)

Running this code downloads and installs the module so I can use it in Terminal:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> print(scipy.pi)
3.141592653589793
```

However Blender doesn't see the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Text", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

What I noticed is that if I try to run the install code again, I see this in the console:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.83/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.83/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scipy) (1.17.0)
```

So `scipy` is located in `./.local` and other modules are in `Blender.app/Contents/`. Does anyone know how can I fix this and use `scipy` in my addon?

Comment: Use `bpy.app.binary_path_python` to get the path to Blender's Python as shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168448/bundling-python-library-with-addon).

Comment: @RobertGützkow thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it's not: when I use your example to install a module I don't have (`matplotlib` you had there) it works, when I changed it to `scipy` I got the same warning as before: `Requirement already satisfied` + failed to import the module https://imgur.com/a/pbA4FC2

Comment: @RobertGützkow ok so I manually uninstalled `scipy` that I had before, reinstalled it from your addon and it works now, thank you! Do you have any idea what has happened? I checked and `bpy.app.binary_path_python` was the same path that I used in my script (`str(py_exec)`). Was it because something about using a wrong pip..?

Comment: You don't have to use the `--user` flag. There are some improvements planned that would allow this to work properly, but they are not implemented yet (see https://developer.blender.org/T71420)

Comment: You would have to add the modules to your `sys.path` if your using `--user`.

Comment: @RobertGützkow ah, interesting. thank you for the explanation!