# How to install Pyserial for Blender 2.83

Tags: python, external-applications

I was looking at the answers for other Blender versions but it seems like it's always changing.

I don't know if I'm correct but something called "pip" is supposed to come with blenders python in 2.83
and you're supposed to use that to install a custom module.

My end goal is to be able to use "import serial" with my scripts.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139718/install-pip-and-packages-from-within-blender-os-independently   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149944/how-to-write-my-add-on-so-that-when-installed-it-also-installs-dependencies-let   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules

Answer (score 1):

I followed this tutorial: http://www.techmonkeybusiness.com/hand-installing-pyserial-into-python-installations.html

The tutorial says:

1. **Download** the [pyserial source code](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial). The file you're looking for ends with .tar.gz
2. **Unzipp** what you've downloaded
3. **Copy** the `serial` **folder** it is under `PySerial\pyserial-3.2.1\serial` (the version can change)
4. **Paste** the folder in your blender modules folder `2.83\scripts\modules`

and now you should be able to use `import serial`