# Installing python module

Tags: python

So supposedly installing a specific module for Blender's python is easy as pie but I can't do it for some reason. I've followed this topic [How to install Pip for Blender's bundled Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-install-pip-for-blenders-bundled-python)

and this website http://www.codeplastic.com/2019/03/12/how-to-install-python-modules-in-blender/

Blender 2.8+ is supposedly shipping with pip already installed. So it should just be a matter of installing the module I want with pip from the Python exe inside the Blender folder. But here are all my failing attempts... What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: Don't start the Python interpreter/console, simply open the directory and run your `pip install` command.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-install-pip-for-blenders-bundled-python#comment254819_56013   `pip` is run from the terminal command line, not the python console