# Installing module to blender's python (Mac)

Tags: python, scripting, installation, osx

I'm trying to install modules (one of them is [open3d](http://www.open3d.org/download/)) with `pip` command.
From 2.8+ it should be easy as `pip install open3d` (mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56013/2214) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167906/installing-python-module#comment283308_167906)), but ...

```
cd /.../Blender\ 92.app/Contents/Resources/2.92/python/bin
python3.7m -m pip install open3d
```

results with Terminal report

```
zsh: command not found: python3.7m
```

The last one thread I found was a [notification](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168482/2214) - pip is installed from 2.8+ for Win, but not for Linux/Mac builds. So I wanted to install `pip` with `ensurepip` as mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-install-pip-for-blenders-bundled-python#comment254819_56013) ... into Blender's bin folder (where python3.7 file is stored) with command ...

```
python3.7m -m ensurepip
```

... but it fails with the same report

```
zsh: command not found: python3.7m
```

Comment: Have you tried just python -m pip install ... (from within the bin folder)

Comment: sure, but it goes to Mac's Python with report "...Python: No module named pip"

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules   @vklidu do you have an installed system python matching blender pythons version? If so (IMO) it is sometimes simplest to `pip install foo --user` to have 3rd party module available for both system and blender python of same version.

Comment: @batFINGER No, system python is 2.7 on Catalina for some reason, so I don't want to break something (also it was recommended https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/fux0iv/python2716_version_showing_in_macos_catalina/fmfe3v1/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 to keep it untouched and rather install python3 within into virtual envi) and also don't install modules globally. So it sounds as more problems for me ...

Comment: @vklidu No??   ,  by system, meant on the system (as opposed to blender python install)  eg via a pyenv, (not changing  your system's  default python) .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-of-pip-install-user    As noted in 3rd party link can remove (rename) blenders python folder and use a  matching  version on your system.

Comment: Sorry, I became lost what is your suggestion ...

Comment: Firstly would be to use  `./python3.7` to avoid the command not found error, when attempting to run  a binary that is in current folder but not in $PATH

Comment: @batFINGER I just get it to work with easy but totally weird solution (answer), but since I very often use experimental version, extending specific blender's python inside a build is not a solution. So when I will have a time I try --user thing :) Thank you for patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2024-02-02

There is an addon for installation and module management https://github.com/amb/blender_pip

---

### Original post ...

For some reason using `cd` to blender's python *bin* folder and then executed command was not working, but ... **path to blender's *bin* folder with *python3.7m* + command** executed at once worked just fine.

---

**Do I have a "pip"?**

I don't know if 2.80 was distributed without a pip (as mentioned above), but 2.79 and also 2.83 Mac build containes a *pip* ... executing `ensurepip` was satisfied. You can check that by right click on *Blender.app icon > Show Package Contents > Contents > Resources > 2.9x > python > bin*, drag&drop bin folder into Terminal window, type `python3.7m -m ensurepip` and execute. In my case it looked like ...

```
/Users/Filip/Downloads/Blender\ 92.app/Contents/Resources/2.92/python/bin/python3.7m -m ensurepip
```

**Upgrade "pip"**

Terminal recommend update *pip* to latest version. So copy&paste directory of *bin* folder or drag&drop *bin* folder again  into *Terminal* window, type  `python3.7m -m pip install --upgrade pip` and execute. My example ...

```
/Users/Filip/Downloads/Blender\ 92.app/Contents/Resources/2.92/python/bin/python3.7m -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Module installation**

From what I tried, even without *pip* care I could just install module by command
`python3.7m -m pip install` + type your module name. In my case *open3d* module...

```
/Users/filip/Downloads/Blender\ 92.app/Contents/Resources/2.92/python/bin/python3.7m -m pip install open3d
```