# How to install Python Modules in Blender?

Tags: python, scripting

I tried to install pythonnet in Blender (v2.83) using Windows Power Shell:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\bin"
cd ..
.\bin\python.exe -m ensurepip
.\bin\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
.\bin\python.exe -m pip install pythonnet
```

pythonnet is now correctly present in the pip list. This procedure worked well for example for opencv-python or python-docx.

But after the installation of pythonnet I cannot import the clr namespace in Blender console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clr'
```

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Pip for Blender's bundled Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-install-pip-for-blenders-bundled-python) specifically this part `$ /path/to/blenderspython/pip install module`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no: I successfully installed pip for Blender's bundled Python, and it worker for other packages, like python-opencv or python-docx. I have the error only with pythonnet.

Comment: IMO would go down the virtual environment road. Make a `venv` from blender's python install, or  a python install of same version dot subversion, point the environment variable `BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON` to it and start blender from it.

Answer (score 3):

How to install any module in Blender:

1. Give complete permissions to the users of Blender's Python folder: `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\python` (Change the path accordingly to your version. Allowing complete permissions can be risky: do it under your own responsibility. I dind't search for the minimal permissions required yet.)
2. Download `get-pip.py` and put it in `...\python\bin` folder
3. From cmd install pip: `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\python\bin>python.exe get-pip.py`
4. Now you can install any modules `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\python\bin>python.exe -m pip install pythonnet`