# Install torch in blender

Tags: python, installation

I need to install torch in blender.
I've Blender 2.92.0 version installed in Ubuntu 20.04.

While trying to ensurepip I've the following issue:

```
(base) paolo@paoloIns:/snap/blender/111/2.92/python$ sudo ./bin/python3.7m -m ensurepip
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpf8idgzxo
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/snap/blender/111/2.92/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easy_install.py'
```

How can I solve this "Errno 30" ?

Comment: Are you running the console in administrator mode ?

Comment: Yes, I've used `sudo` before the command `./bin/python3.7m -m ensurepip`

Comment: Try installing pip, ensurepip, and torch within blender's Text Editor. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283142/142292