# Is it possible to get the current time in Blender?

Tags: python

I want to get the current time in Japan, not the keyframe time
And it will set AM00:00 as 0 seconds
AM00:01=60
AM00:10=600
AM00:30=1800
AM01:30=5400...
I want to change all hours and minutes to seconds like this
How can I display that in Node's Value?

Comment: If you're wiling to use some Python to drive a node's value(s), getting the current time in a target time zone seems to be easy to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442049/python-give-utc-time-get-time-in-japan-using-pytz

Comment: This did not work in TextEditor or in the Python console...

Comment: Oh, apologies; I should have looked into the StackOverflow I linked a bit more. They don't show the full script -- it should be `import datetime; import pytz; datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))`. But, `pytz` is not installed by default with Blender's copy of Python, so you would have to separately install it for this to work

Comment: If you would like to install `pytz`, you can do so (using one of the methods in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/240347/73773) by closing Blender, navigating to your Blender's installation folder, into the Python sub-folder, executing `./python.exe -m pip install pytz`, and re-opening Blender. After doing this, the command should work in your Blender Python console, and return `datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 14, 5, 49, 17, 84151, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)`

Comment: can u please tell us what you want to do further with your "node value", which has then the time? which normally is a string...and until now you cannot do that much with a string in gn right now....i would understand it a bit more if you want to have e.g. the hours in an integer value....

Answer (score 4):

This is not specific to Blender, but Python by itself can do that using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

Result:

```
Current Time = 14:38:17
```

Comment: Oh!!!! Thank you very much!
How can I use this with Node's Value?

Comment: I would need to know more about what you are trying to do with that. Do you intend to create a new node with the current time displayed, or you want to get the current time as a data to use in a node tree ? Would it be in shader, geometry or compositing node systems?

Comment: Hmm Sorry...I would be happy if I could enter it as an expression in the Value node, is that possible?
https://i.imgur.com/92CMAF0.png
I thought this method would work for both Shader and Geometry nodes

Comment: The ting is, the value node only supports only float numbers. A time stamp is a string. You would need to convert this into a float somehow, or use a float in the first place. For example instead of writing `14:38:17` you could output `1438,17`. But what are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe there's a better solution that using a time stamp in the first place?

Comment: now returns an object that has fields for hours, minutes, and seconds, so the conversion would be easy.  The real problem is that there's no way to insert that value into an Input Node in real time.