# How to install opencv-python and opencv in blender 3.0 windows

Tags: python

I am trying to install some libraries like opencv-python and mediapipe in Blender (Windows 10, Blender version 3.0). I have used the following commands to install opencv:

`cd` [Navigate to where python.exe is in blender folder]

The path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin
```

In command prompt I execute the following statement:

```
python.exe -m pip install opencv-python
```

This gives me the following message:

> Defaulting to user-installation because normal site package is not writeable

I already have anaconda3 (python-spyder installed on my windows system which I am using for other ML work). So is it possible that installation is causing some clashes?

I also tried the following script:

```
import subprocess
    import sys
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "ensurepip"])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,"-m","pip","install","opencv-python"])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,"-m","pip","install","opencv-contrib-python"])
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "mediapipe"])
```

After the script is executed, when I try to import cv2/mediapipe I am getting no module found error.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-install-pip-for-blenders-bundled-python

Comment: I don't use Anaconda, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67854154/1149282) which suggests to use `conda deactivate` twice. However, in case Anaconda is just completely unrelated, try running your command line as an administrator and try installing Blender outside of special folders like Program Files.

Comment: Crantisz that was the first thing I looked at,as for markus's suggestion,even after deactivating I am still getting the error

Comment: I was able to get the installations done,apparently I had to use pip --t as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915471/install-a-python-package-into-a-different-directory-using-pip