# How to open Blender's image using Pillow?

Tags: python, scripting, image

I'm using PIL to an addon I'm working on and at some point I need to open images using pillow. The usual way to do is

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open('whatever your image is')
```

But with images created within Blender, the only access is using
`bpy.data.image['the image']` which causes error using `Image.open` from PIL.

I get the following error when I type:
`Image.open(bpy.data.image['test'])`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3096, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3098, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I found some idea using pixels and `Image.fromarray` but nothing conclusive so far...

How do you load Blender's image like `bpy.data.image['the image']` into PIL image?

Comment: I guess you installed PIL to your local python, but have you installed it in your Blender installation's own python? AFAIK they are completelly independant.  [How to install python modules in blender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68964354/10705720) Besides, this raises the question: how will you distribute your addon and make it easier for its users to install it with its dependencies.

Comment: The installation folder doesn't seems to be the issue, I made a similar thing to the link you share (thanks by the way). The issue here is opening the image.

Comment: If you're asking a question about a script it's usually a good idea to post the script in the question. The error can only tell us so much about your issue.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to reference a blender `bpy.types.Image` as if it were a `PIL.Image` but those are not the same thing. [bpy](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image) vs. [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) objects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71397984/how-can-i-use-pil-in-python

Comment: added the command line that generates the error, thanks for the comments above.

Comment: Try to pass the filepath of the image, instead of the image object: Image.open(bpy.data.images['imgName.png'].filepath_raw). Or another way could be to save the created image to actually create the file in the disk, and then pass that filepath to Image.open().

Comment: Yes that's the current workaround I consider, though some images are generated in blender and not imported. Saving them locally works indeed, but at larger scale with 100+ Textures and images for large scenes it might become heavy and space/memory consuming (even if deleting the temporary images).

Answer (score 1):

The method [`Image.open`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-open-method/) is only used to open file paths. But you can simply transform the pixels into bytes and use [`Image.frombytes`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-frombytes-method/) instead to get the pillow image:

```
import bpy
from PIL import Image
import io
import struct

img = bpy.data.images['test']

pixels = [int(px * 255) for px in img.pixels[:]]
bytes = struct.pack("%sB" % len(pixels), *pixels)

image = Image.frombytes('RGBA', (img.size[0], img.size[1]), bytes)
image = image.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).rotate(180)

image.show()
```

For those who have not installed the [`PIL`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) module. You can install it with the following script using [`pip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_pip.asp).

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
 
python_exe = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python.exe')

subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'ensurepip'])
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pillow'])
```

You can read more about [installing python modules here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-install-pip-for-blenders-bundled-python). Note that the original Python Imaging Library (PIL) was the popular image processing library for Python. However, development on PIL ceased a long time ago, and the project was dormant for several years. As a result, the community created a fork of PIL called Pillow to continue its development and maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on great answer of Harry McKenzie just for convenience for the next guy looking for this:

```
import bpy
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import io
import struct
import numpy as np

try:
    from PIL import Image
except: 
    python_exe = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python.exe')
    subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'ensurepip'])
    subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])
    subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pillow'])
    
def pil_to_image(pil_image, name='NewImage'):
    width, height = pil_image.width, pil_image.height
    normalized = 1.0 / 255.0
    bpy_image = bpy.data.images.new(name, width=width, height=height)
    bpy_image.pixels[:] = (np.asarray(pil_image.convert('RGBA'),dtype=np.float32) * normalized).ravel()
    return bpy_image

def image_to_pil(bpy_image):
    img = bpy_image
    pixels = [int(px * 255) for px in bpy_image.pixels[:]]
    bytes = struct.pack("%sB" % len(pixels), *pixels)
    pil_image = Image.frombytes('RGBA', (bpy_image.size[0], bpy_image.size[1]), bytes)
    return pil_image


im = image_to_pil(bpy.data.images["test"])
im = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).rotate(45)
pil_to_image(im)
```