# Why does blender's python use system python's site_packages?

Tags: python, customization, installation

### Please read carefully

this is not about *installing* packages with Blender's python, but rather their reverse - ignoring system packages.

**I DO NOT WANT** Blender to use the packages in `site-packages` - and all those questions are about how you get to do it.

Also - see at bottom: it seems this started with Python 3.10 (Blender 3.1).

---

When I try to install packages with `pip` I installed under Blender, I get messages such as

```
Requirement already satisfied: svgpathtools in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.6.1)
```

However, Blender's python then doesn't find them when executing scripts.

How do I get Blender's pip to **ignore** system python's site_packages?

Right now I am working around this by renaming site_packages, but that's horrible and time consuming.

BTW, this seems new to Blender 3.4 (but no guarantee about that).

This is the command I use:

```
simone$ /home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/bin/pip install scikit-learn
```

and this the output I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.1.1 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
```

and the same results come if I use

```
simone$ /home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/bin/python3.10 -m pip install scikit-learn
```

and this is the screenshot of my preferences:

[image]

with no trace of extra/strange paths being added in.

I've also recursively looked for the string `site-packages` in my `.config/blender` directory and found nothing suspicious - except in dream-textures, which I have since deleted - with no result.

Just for kicks, I run this script

```
 import sys
 for p in sys.path:
     print(p)
```

on all pythons in all my blender installs. This is the result:

##### /home/simone/blender/blender-2.93.14-linux-x64/2.93/python/bin/python3.9

```
/home/simone/blender/blender-2.93.14-linux-x64/2.93/python/lib/python3.9
/home/simone/blender/blender-2.93.14-linux-x64/2.93/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/home/simone/blender/blender-2.93.14-linux-x64/2.93/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-2.93.14-linux-x64/2.93/python/lib/python39.zip
```

##### /home/simone/blender/blender-3.0.1-linux-x64/3.0/python/bin/python3.9

```
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.0.1-linux-x64/3.0/python/lib/python3.9
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.0.1-linux-x64/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.0.1-linux-x64/3.0/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.0.1-linux-x64/3.0/python/lib/python39.zip
```

##### /home/simone/blender/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/3.1/python/bin/python3.10

```
/home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/3.1/python/lib/python3.10
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/3.1/python/lib/python310.zip
```

##### /home/simone/blender/blender-3.2.0-linux-x64/3.2/python/bin/python3.10

```
/home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.2.0-linux-x64/3.2/python/lib/python3.10
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.2.0-linux-x64/3.2/python/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.2.0-linux-x64/3.2/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.2.0-linux-x64/3.2/python/lib/python310.zip
```

##### /home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/bin/python3.10

```
/home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/lib/python3.10
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/lib/python310.zip
```

##### /home/simone/blender/blender-3.5.0-linux-x64/3.5/python/bin/python3.10

```
/home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.5.0-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.5.0-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.5.0-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.5.0-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python310.zip
```

So it seems like the lookup in my system Python starts with 3.1. What's going on? how can I stop that? Is there a config variable I messed up by mistake?

Comment: Hello, it might come from the way you compiled Blender. Did you use an official distribution ?

Comment: @Gorgious - yes, official download

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie - I get an empty string

Comment: as a workaround could u try add this before u run pip within Text Editor. `unwanted_paths = ['/home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if p not in unwanted_paths]` in blender 3.1 for example

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie - thanks, but add to what?

Comment: when you install a package using [this script here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283142/142292), add this code before pip install. then click Run Script.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you executed the command in a native [Linux Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console) or Terminal:

```
simone$ /home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/bin/pip install scikit-learn
```

You have to be very careful of the subtle differences. You are executing the command within the Terminal which can affect where the packages are installed and whether Blender's Python environment can access them. So I think this is likely the reason you have messed up your environment with previous executions. You should have used the proper way to install Blender Python packages with the method [outlined in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283142/142292) using the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) in Blender to ensure that the package is installed and integrated properly within the context of Blender's Python environment.

[image]

For now as a temporary workaround you could exclude that unwanted path from `sys.path` before running any script that will try to get this path involved. Like for example if you want to install package `scikit-learn`, run the script like this:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os

unwanted_paths = ['/home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if p not in unwanted_paths]
print(sys.path)
python_exe = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python.exe')
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'scikit-learn'])
```

[image]