# Using NumPy in Blender Add-ons Without Requiring External Installation

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, installation, numpy

When developing Blender add-ons, I often find myself in need of the [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) package due to its optimized algorithms for array manipulation. However, a significant hurdle arises from the requirement to install `numpy` using [`pip`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283142/142292). This additional installation step can be daunting for the average user and may hinder the accessibility of my add-on.

Given this constraint, I'm hesitant to rely on external libraries like NumPy. Is it advisable to avoid using such libraries altogether in Blender add-on development, or are there alternative approaches to consider?

One potential solution I'm considering is extracting and including only the necessary parts of NumPy (`np.array`, `np.ndarray`, etc.) within my add-on. However, I'm unsure about the feasibility and potential challenges associated with this approach.

Can anyone provide insights into best practices for incorporating external libraries like NumPy in Blender add-ons while ensuring ease of use for end-users? Additionally, is there a standard technique or process that can be employed to safely include specific parts of NumPy within an add-on, without relying on the user to install it separately?

Any advice or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Blender ships with numpy, you do not need to do anything special to use it beyond `import numpy`.

Comment: woot i think you already installed it via pip. because i remember i had to install it via pip.

Comment: You don't. Many of the addons that ship with Blender use numpy.

Comment: There might be discrepancies between the numpy version used by Blender and the latest available numpy version through pip though, you may have had an error stating a function does not exist because it was part of a more recent release of numpy. or similarly an addon using shipping an older numpy version override blender's default one. But numpy does come with vanilla Blender

Comment: very nice ok thank you for the clarification! so on another note, generally if  a module is not part of blender, it's best to avoid using them in your addon?