# Blender 4 Python Scripting issue: Pyodbc module not found error

Tags: python, scripting

I am a Python noob, trying to make a small script to facilitate the application of materials to a large number of small models making up machines for the company I work for. The script in general works and loads a dictionary from a .txt file containing key, value pairs which reference model names, material names. The higher ups want this to be changed to reading from an sql server table.

While writing said server integration of the blender script I ran into the error:

**Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'**

I have looked around and not found a solution to this issue, I have seen this module be recommended for sql server integration on a few site with other libraries referenced for other server types.

I have only one non default setting applied: **Material Library VX** which is integral to the function of this script.

Anyone have any idea why Blender scripting would be having this error?

Comment: You have to install `pip` and then install the module `pyodbc` using `pip`. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283142/142292

Comment: would that be somehow inside of the blender console? I tried it in the cmd like it recommends to do online but no change, then tried updating pyodbc but same result.