Pandas for Blender 4.3
I am trying to install the python package pandas for use in Blender 4.3. To do so, I am using the following command:
python3 -m pip install pandas --target="/Users/me/Library/Application 
Support/Blender/4.3/scripts/addons/modules"

which correctly installs the package in the desired folder. However, when I type import pandas in the scripting environment of Blender, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/me/Library/Application 
Support/Blender/4.3/scripts/addons/modules/pandas/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from pandas.core.api import (
File "/Users/me/Library/Application 
Support/Blender/4.3/scripts/addons/modules/pandas/core/api.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas._libs import (
File "/Users/me/Library/Application 
Support/Blender/4.3/scripts/addons/modules/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 16, in 
<module>
import pandas._libs.pandas_parser  # isort: skip # type: ignore[reportUnusedImport]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.pandas_parser'

Note that when I use pandas with the system-installed Python everything runs smoothly. It might be something with version compatibility, since Blender uses Python 3.11.9 and my system uses Python 3.13, but I cannot really find any solution. PS: I am using a macbook.

You should search for how to create an environment and use this environment in blender, otherwise you risk messing your blender python irreversibly

Your approach risks interfering with Blender’s internal environment. By installing it in a specific directory, you could cause conflicts with other dependencies or version mismatches, as Blender requires packages to be installed within its own Python environment to function correctly. To do that, install the package directly from within Blender using the Text Editor or Python Console to ensure proper integration with Blender’s environment. Please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283142/142292

Then you can install pandas using something like python_exe = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python.exe') and subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pandas'])

I actually solved it using python wheels.
