# How to write a YAML file with a Blender Python script

Tags: python

I need to write a script that runs on Blender (2.72) and writes a YAML file containing the results. In normal python I would use `PyYAML` and write something like:

```
import yaml
yaml.dump(['some', 'data'])
....
```

It seems that Blender uses a different python interpreter than the one installed on my system (Ubuntu), thus, a different set of extensions. I tried copying the `PyYAML` installation files to the Blender script directory `blender/2.72/scripts/modules`. That way, I can import the library, but I get errors because the library has its own dependencies (I want to avoid having to install every sub-dependency manually).

**How can I get a Python extension installed and working in Blender?**

**Is there an alternative method to write YAML files in Blender (using python)?**

Note: I will distribute the blender file containing the python script to other users, so it would be nice to have an easy-setup method!

Comment: PyYaml is not bundled with blender, you need to install it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules-scipy