# How Can Data Sets Be Pulled From Database into Text Objects or As Parameters for Other Objects

Tags: python, animation, scripting, workflow

I would like to build animations based on 2 scenarios that pull data into Blender from SQLite, MongoDB or MySQL database.

One scenario where a bit of text data would become a simple text object would be a movie post credit roll animation. In this case, numerical data from an external file would control the size, radius or constraint controls of objects in the animation.

How can I get information from an external file and use that to control properties (sometimes animated) of various objects?

Answer (score 3):

Your question comprises 3 different topics:

1. How to query for data in a backend (SQLite or whatever)
2. How to do that with Python (database drivers / libraries)
3. How to create animations in Blender programmatically

There's a brief introduction for the latter in the API docs - [Animation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/info_quickstart.html#animation) - and plenty of questions and threads here and on [blenderartists.org](http://blenderartists.org).

For 1., please refer to the database system's documentation and help channels.

For 2., google and also read about [using 3rd party Python modules in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules).