# modeling in blender by taking input from wireless media controlled by autonomous system

Tags: game-engine

anybody knows how to take command from wireless media like xbee modules and according to that command modeling is done without human intervention.
        I have one xbee module on a micro-controller which sends information about objects detected to another xbee module connected to PC. how blender can perform modeling (like placing detected object on the map created in blender ) using the information received by xbee module. 
        I just want to know the way in which i can take input for my python script from the xbee. Do anybody know how to do it?

Comment: I guess you need to import the according python module that is the python binding to the xbee module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need a python module that will talk to your xbee. The [XBee](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee/2.2.3) module doesn't mention what python versions it works with, but it uses [pyserial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial/3.2.1) which does support python3.5. If that doesn't work, [searching pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=xbee&submit=search) for xbee shows a few other possibilities.

There are a few ways to [install third party modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5287/935) or you can [make blender use the system python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30517/935). You can also add a path to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) so that blenders python can search for it.

Once you are able to import the module within blender create a script that responds to the input. You may want to look at using the subprocess module to read the input [without locking blenders UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45731/935).