# How to import odeint python module from scipy into blender

Tags: python, scripting, import

I need to import `odeint` module from `scipy.integrate` in Blender.
I successfully imported `scipy` copying in

> blender dir\2.80\python\lib\site-packages\

the `scipy` directories from Anaconda's site-packages dir.
I tried to import `odeint` from `scipy.integrate` and I got an error:

```
>> from scipy.integrate import odeint

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mcrim\Downloads\blender-2.80.0-git.9315cc443b1d-windows64\2.80\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .quadrature import *
  File "C:\Users\mcrim\Downloads\blender-2.80.0-git.9315cc443b1d-windows64\2.80\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.special import roots_legendre
  File "C:\Users\mcrim\Downloads\blender-2.80.0-git.9315cc443b1d-windows64\2.80\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
```

I am running this configuration:

Blender:

version: 2.80 (sub 45), branch: master, commit date: 2019-02-20 13:47,
build date: 20/02/2019, 06:10
platform: Windows 10 64 bit

> EDIT: I followed this procedure:
>   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122337/71402 but it installs scipy
>   in system-wise python directory, not in blender python directory

Comment: A lot of python modules have to be installed, not simply copied. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules (possible duplicate) I use system python, or a pip --user install (have to be same version / subversion eg 3.7 or 3.7.1 are compat.  Not 3.6 and 3.7)

Comment: See original question: I edited infos following a procedure in the link you provided

Comment: Hmmm thought it was another link where an answer (or as mentioned in the deleted one there) "_Delete the Python which is bundled with Blender, forcing Blender to fallback to the systems Python installation._"  (rather than delete can rename it _python (eg) and restart blender)  To re-iterate versions need to match.  If this works ok, then anything you can install on your system you can use in blender.  Not a user of anaconda to test that environment.

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41258/install-python-module-for-blender

Comment: Following procedures above, I finally imported scipy module in Blender. I've needed to install numpy==1.15.0 version instead of 1.16.0 to make it work.