# accessing Blender objects from external Python IDEs

Tags: python, external-applications

I would like to manipulate Blender objects from Spyder (not using the internal Python editor). Basically I would like to have Blender running and Spyder running as well, and then interactively access objects in Blender. Examples which allow access to the Python API from external scripts is QGIS and ArcGIS.

A typical user journey would be:

1. Open Spyder, Rodeo, etc.
2. import relevant Blender libraries
3. get list of available objects in scene
4. get data on one the objects
5. edit object
6. write object back to Blender

I found this Blender module: 
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule 
... but I'm not sure if this is what I need.

I'm not looking for using Python modules within Blender as described here: 
[Using Anaconda Python 3 in Blender Winx64](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51067/)