# Properly Installing Pillow

Tags: python, scripting

I have a project I need [**Pillow**](https://python-pillow.org/) for. Is there a way to install it into blender 2.77a? The pillow windows installer just finds a python version if I install one seperatly. If I can not install "pillow" directly, is there a way to use the pre-installed python 3.5.1?
I already tried to delete the python directory and to copy the site-packages.

[Other solutions found on Stack-Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules) do not work for me, maybe they do not work for Windows, maybe not for blender 2.77a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a guess, but you might want to [use a external Python 3 for using Blender scripts](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?234399-Need-help-by-using-an-external-python-module-in-Blender-bounded-Python) instead of the bundled one. Since the installer does automatically set the registry, Pillow'll probably recognize it.

Comment: That is probably the case. How do I use an external python version @Gustavo6046?

Comment: @schustudrai [This](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?234399-Need-help-by-using-an-external-python-module-in-Blender-bounded-Python) might also help.

Comment: With the solution there I can import PIL, but as soon as I try importing anything else I get another error:  ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Reinstalling Python and Pillow helped the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of Blender's suggested solutions is to outright remove the bundled python environment. Blender will then fall back on your system default, and whatever libraries you have installed there.

Just make sure you have a compatible python version installed (e.g, as of writing python is currently released at 3.9, but blender currently uses 3.7)

Source: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html#bundled-python-extensions