# Turn rendered plane into a 3D digital object

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I am quite new to Blender, I hope this question is okay. I have rendered a plane(surface) using elevation data of a mountain range (see photo). Is there any way that I can now export this as an object that can be zoomed into and out of / rotated with the mouse? Thanks.[image: final render]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/using-blender-game-engine-for-vr-360-tour-on-mobile-is-it-doable/53938 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64274/is-blender-a-sensible-environment-for-making-a-first-person-orrery

Comment: If that elevation data is used as displacement map with microdisplacement feature then you have to bake it before using anywhere else and reconstruct displacement in the end application or add resulting displacement map to Displace modifier, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY

Comment: Or instead of using microdisplacement you can use a displacement modifier, that will create real geometry.