# How to make a interactive 3D scene/environment out of something created in Blender?

Tags: export, workflow

This question may not be directly related to Blender itself and it's more like a general 3D question. If it's too off topic excuse me and let me know so I can have it deleted.

I've started learning Blender not too long ago and I'm loving it. I use it mainly to showcase products. For example, if it's a lamp, I will just create a simple interior scene and have it displayed which always comes out beautifully.

I was wondering, would it be possible to create a scene/world in Blender, like a house for example, pre-render it and have the user be able to explore it, using a controller like mouse & keyboard or VR? Like a virtual showroom.

This may also sound like I'm trying to create a game. Which is not exactly what I'm aiming for but I'm open to the idea of creating a super simple game in something like Unity for example to achieve this. My concern is, I don't want to  re-create the scene, or objects in another 3D software. I'm hoping I can somehow move/transfer the thing I created in Blender.

I had a look at `three.js` library which seems to be used to create 3D scenes in the browser, but It appears it requires to recreate the whole scene in it, have each object created separately and position it using numbers. Also it uses it's own render engine which looks cartoony and isn't photorealistic-like which is what I'm looking for.

Any thoughts and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/using-blender-game-engine-for-vr-360-tour-on-mobile-is-it-doable/53938 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64274/is-blender-a-sensible-environment-for-making-a-first-person-orrery/64277