# Installing a Python module in Blender's Python API

Tags: python, scripting

(This is related to [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules?newreg=1cac182afd1a4398bd801490ee82903c))

I would like to add a module to Blender's Python (Blender v2.76). I want to follow the solution outlined in the link above, but my Blender directory does not have a 2.7x subdirectory. Could this be because I am using 2.76, and the answer uses version 2.72?

The output of running `ls` in my blender directory is the following:

```
GPL-license.txt                 blender.app
GPL3-license.txt                blenderplayer.app
LICENSE-bfont.ttf.txt           copyright.txt
LICENSE-bmonofont-i18n.ttf.txt  game
LICENSE-droidsans.ttf.txt       jemalloc-license.txt
LICENSE-libiomp5.txt            readme.html
Python-license.txt              startScript.txt
blen files
```

Where `blen files` and `game` are my own subdirectories.  From my understanding of the related answer, I would simply need to the Python module I need in the `/blender/2.72/python/lib/python3.4/` directory?

What should I do if this directory is missing? This is strange, because I can script in Python, from within Blender, even though this directory is missing...

Answer (score 2):

Python loads any module from the directories in `sys.path`. Try this in the interactive Python console in Blender:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))
```

That'll give you a choice of paths. Alternatively, you can place your scripts next to your blend file, and in the blend file text editor itself have a script like this:

```
import bpy
import sys

p = bpy.path.abspath('//scripts')
if p not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(p)
```

Make sure the script name ends in `.py` and the 'Register' checkbox is checked. After this runs you can import Python modules from the `scripts` subdirectory of whichever directory holds your blend file.

Also make sure that the directory names are actually valid Python names, so without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on an unix system (DUH). maybe "2.7X" is in a nereby location (if blender's directory isn't directly /usr/share/blender and if there isn't any "blender_2.76" dir next to it.) maybe in "/usr/lib/blender"?

If not, you could see the "file" property seen in any addon's details

Answer (score 0):

In a script, you can access modules installed on your system within Blender this way:

```
import sys
DIR = '/home/username/.local/lib/python3/dist-packages/MODULE/'
sys.path.append('DIR')
import MODULE
```

Just tell it what dir to use, and the module name.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around this would be to compile Blender as a Python module. This way, you can easily do `import bpy` in your system's Python installation (Python 3.6 and above as of October 2018). What you have to do is to download Blender's source code from [here](https://www.blender.org/download/) by clicking on the drop-down menu and selecting *Source Code*. If you're on Windows, you should follow [these instructions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119837/how-can-one-do-rendering-with-cycles-using-an-nvidia-rtx-gpu/119840#119840) to compile Blender. Just make sure you set the CMake flag the Python module to enabled (shown below). If you're on a Unix-based operating system you should first execute `/blenderSourceCode/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh` to install the dependencies and then use CMake to generate the make files as follow:

```
cd blenderSourceCodeDir
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages \
  -DWITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON \
  -DPYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages \
make -j 4
make install
```

This way you can install any package through `pip` or other tools and import them alongside the `bpy` module as follow:

```
python3 -m pip install h5py
python3 -m pip install scipy

python3 -c "import bpy; import h5py; import scipy; print ('done')"
```

Comment: Official instructions on how to build blender can be found here: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender Also I'd suggest *cloning the repo* instead of *downloading the source code* @Amir

Comment: @p2or I always clone the repo myself but I thought this might be easier for the average user :)