# How do you use your system's Python with Blender?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

As the title sais; I'd like to use my system's Python with Blender, instead of the internal one, but after searching for ~30 minutes I still couldn't find a way how, or at least not in words I understood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 3rd party Python modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules)

Comment: that one is about using modules from your system python, and though the most upvoted answer does have a method for using system Python, it doesn't work - it just makes it so Blender won't start.

Comment: oh I think I migth have a different version of Python. Lemme check.

Comment: As mentioned there, for it to work you must use the same Python version (which changes depending on Blender's version, and the correct bit version - 32 / 64) as that one used by Blender. Most likely that's why it doesn't work in your case.

Comment: I just checked - I seem to have a slightly newer version of Python.

Comment: alot newer version*

Comment: It didn't work. It still gives the same error, even after setting the compatible version of Python as default.

Comment: Are you sure the compatible version is set as the active default python on your system?

Comment: Pretty sure. I installed the compatible version, then renamed the commands that start Python (so the default command would start the compatible version). I even tried temporarily deleting the uncompatible version.

Answer (score 1):

$ blender --python-use-system-env
Allow Python to use system environment variables such as 'PYTHONPATH' and the user site-packages directory.