# Install pip in blender 2.78 SSLError

Tags: python

I've just downloaded Blender 2.78 (from [here](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/blender-2.78a-linux-glibc211-x86_64.tar.bz2)). I would like to install scipy. Therefor, I want to install pip using [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). I've downloaded the file and executed it as follows:

```
bin/python3.5m get-pip.py
```

This results in the following output:

```
Collecting pip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)'),)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)'),)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)'),)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)'),)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)'),)': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)'),)) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
```

There are many people with the same error message, but they get this message when they try to install a package using pip.

Using a proxy does not solve the problem.

I'm using blender in a docker with Ubuntu 4.15.0-54.58-generic 4.15.18

Does anyone of you know the error?

Comment: This is likely caused by an older version of the OpenSSL lib or misconfiguration. Seems like your script tries to create a TLS connection with the very out-dated version 1 and the pypi server refuses the connection. See the following link on different approaches how to install packages: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules
Also, if you just installed Blender I'd either go with 2.8 or the most recent version of 2.79 depending on which UI your more comfortable with.

Comment: In the newer versions you can simply use ensurepip, as described in the link answer.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to install pip using NAS' answer.
The problem stays the same, more or less. I can not install anything, probably due to an old openssl version ( ´bin/python3.5m -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"´returns ´OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010´).
´bin/pip3 install scipy -v´ raises ´SSLError(e, request=request)´ (even if I set trusted hosts)
Do you have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: I've checked and this is because the old python uses an out-dated version of OpenSSL. Since you can't just upgrade the entire Python used in Blender, your best bet is to install 2.79b which is compatible in the Python API. There are others ways to fix it, but none that are straight forward.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that and let you know if that works for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.