# Compiling Blender to use system Python

Tags: python, linux, compile

**Context**:

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 for the moment and the default repository Blender package use the system's Python 3 which is very convenient because I can use my Python modules in my Blender Scripts without extra steps. The issue is that Ubuntu's current package have a Blender version (2.8) compiled without SubDivision. So Subdivision modifiers don't work.

**Question**:
I manage to clone Blender's git repository and compile it, but I can't figure out what `cmake` commands I need to modify/set to make python use system's python and not the separate `share/python3.7m` version that creates?

Comment: As long as you are compiling against same system version.subversion you can simply remove or rename the bundled python folder of your build.  I use `mv python _python` in a `build_blender.sh`

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules

Comment: Thanks, as you said removing the python bundle folder solve it. That force blender to use the system Python. More here: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_69_release/info_tips_and_tricks.html#bundled-python-extensions