# How to examine a collada file loaded in blender ? (Python)

Tags: python, import, collada, dae

By doing various tests and using `bpy.ops.wm.collada_import()`, there are compatibility problems between some software with the `'.dae'` format, so I was wondering, is there any way to interact with objects inside a `'.dae'` file , before uploading it? Is there a way that allows me to examine the objects present in a dae? with their names and data?
When the object is imported into `bpy.data.objects`, does any trace of property dae remain?

Basically some software create instances that enclose other instances, this does not allow blender to maintain the correct hierarchy, so I was wondering if you could analyze a .dae file and possibly act directly on it.
I still don't know how a dae works. so please be patient, i am trying to get a direction for my research to the solution.

Comment: I'm not a coder so just mentioning this just in case it may help.... You can edit .dae files with Notepad or have more control with Notepad++.

Comment: PyCollada might help: https://github.com/pycollada/pycollada

Comment: @brockmann This is a good start, i think, do you know a practical example of blender use with pycollada? Basically, I should correct the relationships in the .dae file, but I don't know how to interact with this module

Comment: Pure python. If you want to embed it inside blender for whatever reason, read [Using 3rd party Python modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules). How to use the module: https://pycollada.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @brockmann It sounds very interesting, but I was wondering, is there a way to put that module into an addon and call it with the use like: from . import Collada ? I don't want to install it

Comment: Why not? Just make sure the license type match with yours or ask in their mailing list if that's ok or not.

Comment: @brockmann I'm trying to approach this pycollada module, have you ever had anything to do with pycollada on blender? How can I find examples on blender ? Is it appropriate that I ask a new question?

Comment: @brockmann I think your comment about pycollada is my answer, so I invite you to use that comment as an answer so that I can rate it as an answer to my question.

Comment: Glad that my comment was useful @Pastrokkio. Problem is: I have no idea about pycollada itself so I don't want to give any unproven answer. Also I don't want to spend any time on that because I personally don't use it and never will. Thanks though.