# Import external py script into blender script?

Tags: python, scripting, import

I wrote a py script for a custom export. I'd like to append that script to my blend file and call it using some parameters. The following script is one folder above my blend file:

```
from sys import path
path.append('//../fbx_collection_export.py')
from fbx_collection_export import export
```

When running it, I get the this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbx_collection_export'

**Q:** What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add a directory path to the system  path not a filepath. (Not a relative path either) See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules

Comment: thank you @batFINGER that was the issue

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, not as edit to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sys import path
path.append(bpy.path.abspath("//")+'/../Scripts')
from fbx_collection_export import export
```