# How do I Include / add path to blender's python to read extra directory

Tags: python, scripting

I get warnings while installing modules with pip from command line and I think this is one of other issues that I must solve to make Tensorflow work with blender

`WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter.exe, saved_model_cli.exe, tensorboard.exe, tf_upgrade_v2.exe, tflite_convert.exe, toco.exe and toco_from_protos.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\game tools\UPBGE-EEVEE-Win64-2020-08-19\Release\2.91\python\Scripts' which is not on PATH.`

`Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

How do I add additional path to blender's python to include the \Scripts directory that python says it's not in it's path but it's out of path.  It installs things there instead of installing them in folders where python knows about. This is not the main script directory of blender, it is an additional one that installs things there when installing software with pip. "Python -m pip Install" from the python bin directory where python.exe is.

So files get copied there and python does not access them because it's not in it's reference pathways.
How do I add this directory so python also looks there in `\2.91\python\Scripts`

After installing tensorflow with warnings When I type in blender console "import tensorflow" I get lines upon lines of error and I think most of these come from this problem.

So how do I add a path to include the `\2.91\python\Scripts` directory.
I looked in various places but did not find anything, is there a file inside blender to make python look, to add lines to reference the directory ?

Comment: Related: [Using 3rd party Python modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules)

Comment: I found out that it does not install well on some processors that do not have AVX support, and this can be newer i proccessors that don't have this never mind the old ones that also don't  https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel    and here we indeed find that they made some whls without AVX to work on cpus that don't have AVX,  I tried to install one but I get error installations, it refuses to install, gives errors , maybe because they are not official, my pip installer works fine with other packages, but these, none of them work installing.

Comment: So if anyone tries them, please post back here your findings and how well did it go for you, official AVX versions that come in the form of "exe" will give errors upon trying to import them into blender, but they will install without much fuss, but these other ones won't install for me.