# How to include my custom function into blender?

Tags: python

How is the simplest way to import/include my custom function to blender ?  How to add not using install addons ? I don't need to register it as menu. I just want to be able to run/call my function from inside blender for every blender session.

Comment: You don't want to make an addon, no operator, no menu, etc.and you want to run it from the text editor? Include the function text in the text editor and save your startup file.

Comment: not running it from text editor,  wanna make my custom function library so i can re use it when making addon.  multiple addon can use/import this function. so easier to maintain if i need to modify /update it.

Comment: The path should be updated for your Blender version, but this should work https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the information.