# cant upgrade pip in blender 2.92

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am fairly new to Python and Blender so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I have been trying to install an add-on for Sverchok (Scipy), but I cant install it using the pip option.

I get a message saying I need to upgrade pip, when I try to upgrade it, this is what outputs to the python console in blender:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/ef/60d7ba03b5c442309ef42e7d69959f73aacccd0d86008362a681c4698e83/pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/d4/b99a960314121a003e9f39c61dfde01a1010bb47661e193a7722f7f32d52/setuptools-54.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (785kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 788kB 6.4MB/s
Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/63/39d04c74222770ed1589c0eaba06c05891801219272420b40311cd60c880/wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\blender foundation\\blender 2.92\\2.92\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I found this link https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-install-required-packages-to-the-blender-python-with-pip/ which looked promising. But when I attempted to run this (by opening a text window, click new, pasting the code and clicking run) image below of what I have setup in blender) it says it cant install due to WinError 5 Access denied.

[image]

The output in python console in blender is this:

```
Looking in links: c:\Users\CJHMHTPC\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp57u_wh4u
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 2.92\2.92\python\lib\site-packages (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 2.92\2.92\python\lib\site-packages (19.2.3)
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/ef/60d7ba03b5c442309ef42e7d69959f73aacccd0d86008362a681c4698e83/pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\blender foundation\\blender 2.92\\2.92\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So it seems I don't have permissions for some reason.

I see that it recommends to use --user option, but I don't know what this means or how to use it. I did some googling, but tbh it's all a bit beyond me, so any help people could offer would be much appreciated.

My end goal is to be able to install Scipy in Sverchok so I can use the 3D voronoi node in case that is helpful information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751469/blender-trying-to-install-sverchok-addon-scipy-package-but-pip-is-out-of-date?noredirect=1#comment118112911_66751469
discussing some

Comment: Try running Blender as Administrator...it worked for me :D

Comment: Using `python_exe = sys.executable` will make it compatico with all OS's. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122337/15543  IMO tho would make a python environment matching the python version of blender,  Install any dependencies there.  Run blender using the venv's python.

Comment: @batFINGER - thanks for the link to that thread, I did the second option which was to remove the path (i just renamed the blender python folder). Blander has now defaulted to my system python which has scipy installed with no issues, I can now use the 3D voronoi module, if you put this as an answer I'll add it as the top answer