# Geometry Nodes instance scale based on distance from other instances (Circle Packing)

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, instances

[image]

On the left is a standard instance on points, on the right a sketch of what I want to achieve, where the instances scale based on their distance to the closest other instance.

How can I achieve something like this with Geometry Nodes?
Is it possible?

I've been looking into the Geometry Proximity node but that seems to depend on some other object, which is probably not what I need to solve the problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Personally, I like this question very much, but it also raises a number of other questions for me: Is the number of objects fixed, or does it result from the scaling of the objects? Do the objects always bump into a certain number of their neighbors, or does this result from chance? My first approach would be to use a Voronoi texture as a base, but that probably wouldn't achieve the desired result. Can you be a little more specific about the requirement?

Comment: maybe you could fake it by going by layers, placing big ones first and so on, deleting faces on each iteration... tried something a bit like that [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253749/masking-out-overlapping-instances-in-geometry-nodes/253882#253882) but with vertex weights

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note:** A real "Circle Packing" cannot be realized with *Geometry Nodes* alone, because essential nodes like e.g. Loops are missing.
>
> Therefore, there is no way around an additional tool if you really want to solve it well.

I offer two solutions here, a simple one *(which only partially leads to a useful result)*, and one that does exactly what you are looking for with the help of an external *Python library*.

### Solution 1 (the simple variant):

Here, only by distorting a grid and the resulting area of a face, a possible value for a radius is derived. This is visually close to the solution and may be sufficient in some cases, but it is not really a nice solution and certainly not a "real" *circle packing*.

[image: Circle Packing - Fake]

[image]

### Solution 2 (with the help of Python):

If you want to implement real *Circle Packing*, you probably won't be happy with Geometry Nodes alone.
Basically, you would need to be able to measure the distance of each circle center to any other point (within a certain radius?), and probably repeat this process several times to get a reliable result.

As I said, this is actually what is meant by true "*Circle Packing*".

Presumably, though, it would be possible to program the algorithm in Python, and that would generate for you the circle centers and the radii of the circles needed for Geometry Nodes.

Search for *"Circle Packing Delaunay Triangulation"*.

...and that's what I did, and I found a solution.

Thanks to a sufficiently stable but very lean implementation in Python, which I personally liked a lot and which was published by [mhtchan](https://github.com/mhtchan) under the *MIT license* on Github, I was now able to integrate this into Blender.

You can find the project here: [packcircles](https://github.com/mhtchan/packcircles)

This Python library is simply passed an array with Radii, and it returns you the coordinates of the circles, which you then actually just continue to use in Blender with your geometry nodes.

The way to get there is as follows:

1. To be able to use additional Python libraries in Blender, you have to get them into your system (Windows). The easiest way might be to install the library with pip.

   First open a terminal (cmd.exe) and enter the following *(replace the example path used here with the one of your Blender installation!!)*:

   ```bash
   cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\python\bin"
   python -m ensurepip
   python -m pip install packcircles
   ```

   Another method to install packages directly from Blender is this one:
   [Using 3rd party Python modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules)

   After installation the library is installed in the following path and usable in Blender:
   `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\python\lib\site-packages\`
2. Next Start Blender create a new script and make sure the library is loaded and available:

   ```py
   import packcircles
   ```
3. If everything worked out, you only need to create the following script in the editor.

   Replace the upper variables with the values you want and execute the script:

   ```py
   from bpy import context, data, ops
   import packcircles as pc
   import numpy

   # Define your own values here
   min = 0.5
   max = 1.0
   count = 50
   objectName = 'CirclePack'

   # Generate some random radii in the specified range
   radii = numpy.random.uniform(min, max, size=(1, count))

   # Run the CirclePacking (contains the coordinates and the radius)
   points = list(pc.pack(radii[0]))

   # Check if an object already exists and otherwise create a new one
   if not context.scene.objects.get(objectName):
       # Create a curve (starting with a single point, because we set the points later)
       ops.curve.simple(
           align = 'WORLD',
           location = (0, 0, 0),
           rotation = (0, 0, 0),
           Simple_Type = 'Point',
           use_cyclic_u = False
       )
       # Rename the object so that a easy repetition of this process is possible
       for obj in context.selected_objects:
           obj.name = objectName
           obj.data.name = objectName

   # Enter edit mode
   ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

   # Set curve parameters
   ops.curve.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
   ops.curve.delete(type = 'VERT')
   ops.curve.simple(
       Simple_Type = 'Line',
       shape = '3D',
       outputType = 'POLY',
       use_cyclic_u = False
   )

   # Subdivide the curve so that the number of points equals the number of circles
   ops.curve.subdivide(number_cuts = count - 2)

   # Set curve as active object
   curve = context.active_object

   # Iterate through the circlepacking coordinates
   for i, coordinates in enumerate(points):
       x, y, r = coordinates
       curve.data.splines[0].points[i].co = (x, y, 0, 1)
       curve.data.splines[0].points[i].radius = r

   # Leave edit mode   
   ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
   ```

   Here an array with Radii is passed to the CirclePacking at the beginning, and you get back the coordinates for it.

   To make it easy to process all this in Geometry Nodes, a curve is created with the name you specified, whose points correspond to the positions of the individual circles. In order to be able to position the respective circle in the Geometry Nodes in the appropriate size, a value for the radius is also given to the individual points.

   If you do not rename the created object, you can repeat the process as often as you like.

   All existing points will be removed from the curve and new points will be created randomly.
4. If the script ran without errors, a new curve will be created. It looks a bit strange, so it needs Geometry Nodes now.

   [image: Circle Packing - Curve]

   Add a modifier of type "Geometry Nodes" to the curve and do what ever you want to do with it or use the nodes I attached here in the blend file.

   [image: Circle Packing - Circles]

   Essentially, I don't do much more in this example either. Only circles are instantiated at the points of the curve. Depending on how you additionally influence the radii, different results arise here. Of course, you can also instantiate and scale all unit circles first, and then convert the circles into meshes using the `Curve to Mesh` node.

   [image: Circle Packing - Python]

   And here is the blend file:

   [image]

Comment: These python scripts are on Git hub, so someone proficient in python could adapt them.  Maybe it could be made into a bountied python question?

Comment: @common_goldfish UPDATED! ...is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: For me it is impressive. Thank you for putting it into Blender.

Comment: Amazing!
Thanks a lot :)