# Geometry Nodes Average Position

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to average the position of points in geometry node, kind of a 3D smooth to evenly space elements between each others?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5oYC.jpg

If it is possible, is there a way to do it on curve points?

The idea is to have the points that are close to each other to repel based on their proximity
Here is a more concrete example of what I'm looking for the effect I'm looking for : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h3un.jpg

More Images :

[image]

[image]

I thought of using the geometry proximity node but I couldn't get it to work properly

Comment: so you want equal distances on a curve?

Comment: I'd like to evenly space points of multiple curves to prevent them from overlapping

Comment: I think you'll have to illustrate your specific case. 'Prevent curves from overlapping' seems a very different problem from 'Smooth / Average point locations' ..

Comment: I've added more detail on my post, basically this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253297/geometry-nodes-instance-scale-based-on-distance-from-other-instances-circle-pac  is what I'm trying to achieve, but instead of affecting the scale I'd like the position of each points to be afected