# Geometry Nodes circle packing - high density like beer foam

Tags: geometry-nodes

There are a couple of tutorials for circle packing in Blender's geometry nodes:
[image]
[image]

But there are never really "filling" the space in between the circles, like this:

[image]
Image by [Freepik](https://www.freepik.com/free-photo/foam-texture_3933979.htm#page=2&query=beer%20foam&position=28&from_view=search&track=ais&uuid=8a01183e-0e08-425a-839f-760116ecd0e6)

Is there a way to do that in the current Blender (4)?

Comment: This as interesting question inits own right, but for foam, are you sure you need packing? Bad Normals ' approach [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EZezYWyelM), where small bubbles are masked by big bubbles, is pretty convincing.

Comment: I want to have the real data and to be able to take those circles and switch them with whatever I want (Say - packs of logs). Shading is great, but I want the data

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253297/