# Cannot import module substance_painter.project

Tags: python

I cannot open the substance_painter module in blender

```
import substance_painter.project as sp_project

# Open a Substance Painter project
project = sp_project.load_project('path/to/project.spp')
```

My Blender is installed in default directory aka C:/Program files ....
My Adobe Substance Painter is installed in F:/Adobe/Adobe Substance 3D Painter/Adobe Substance 3D Painter.exe

Other than this there is no difference from default, I tried to run the example code given, but it shows error [image]

I want to be able to import this module so I can work on the code, thank you, if any of you can help
.

Comment: yes, you have to install the module in blender internal python lib

Comment: This should have you covered https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules

Comment: I tried to install the  python lib internally using the steps mentioned, also I tried this user Const in this post, https://blenderartists.org/t/trying-to-install-packages-in-blender/1454124/2

Comment: It does install in blender console when I write the substance api, but still I got got the same problem as I asked the question, Can anyone give me a test example or try to install api needed for the script of this post.