File paths to search for python packages in Blender 4.2
I just installed Blender 4.2, and I tried to check which file paths are searched when running the following code:
import sys
print(sys.path)

It looks like it does not search in the site-packages folder of the Python installation (typically: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages. However, Blender 4.1 searches also in such folder. Any tips?
I also tried to add C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages under Blender Preferences -> File Paths -> Script Directories, but it's not working. Any tips?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules ?

That's actually an old conversation. Not sure if all answers also apply to the newer version of Blender

I ran into a similar problem building an addon for Blender 4.2 It looks like Blender 4.2 no longer automatically searches the user-specific site-packages folder (e.g., C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages).
What worked for me is manually adding the folder to Python's search path.
import site
import sys

user_site_pkgs = site.getusersitepackages()
if user_site_pkgs not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(user_site_pkgs)

Separately, if you want Blender to also check custom directories you've defined in the PYTHONPATH environment variable, you can extend the code like this:
import os

pythonpath_env = os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')
if pythonpath_env:
    for path in pythonpath_env.split(os.pathsep):
        if path not in sys.path:
            sys.path.append(path)

This code checks if PYTHONPATH is set, and if it is, it adds the directories from PYTHONPATH to sys.path.

I am mainly interested in the first piece of code you wrote, and that works, thanks! However, I was wondering how can I include it in a Blender addon script. I tried to add it in the init.py file but I get an error saying that the particular third-party Python package I am using (pvlib) cannot be found. Any ideas?

My initial guess is the actual package was either not installed in the user site-packages directory or the package install was unclean.
A first step to take is to check if the python package is in site-packages. If you're testing in Blender 4.2 you need to look in the python 3.11 version.
The site packages location depends on if you're on Windows, Mac, or Linux.
The "AppData" directory might be hidden, but it should still be there.
Windows
C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages
Mac
/Users/username/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/

Blender comes with its own Python - sorry, I don't know the paths on Windows, but you can find the location by printing sys.exec_prefix from inside Blender (see this stackexchange question). Site packages should then be in lib/python3.x.
Trying to mix packages from your system Python with Blender's own will likely drown you in a mire of version conflicts at some point.
What works for me if I want to add Python modules where Blender can find them:

set up and activate a virtual environment using Blender's Python
pip install explicitly specifying the Blender Python site-packages directory (presumably similar to <blender root>/4.2/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/)

virtualenv --python="Blender's python executable" venv-blender
Run the activation script in venv-blender/bin.
pip install --upgrade -t "path to site-packages" "your package"
Deactivate and delete the virtual env.
Here's a maybe somewhat dated blog post of my procedure on Linux, with some more background links.

It looks a bit more complicated than I expected. I am looking for a simpler procedure (if any!). The installation should be user-friendly, also for users that are not expert in Python. Any tips?

@AlexMekx I'm afraid this feature is not available to total newbies. You can find a way to wrap the logic in a user friendly interface in your addon but if you rely on users doing that themselves they need to have at least a basic understanding of the subject

@Gorgious, I've managed to do it myself, but the idea is to develop an addon that can be easily installed by anyone. It seems that the best option is to enclose the required Python packages directly into the .zip folder. I
