Installing Python packages with pip when Blender has been installed with snap on Ubuntu
I am currently missing some extra packages in the Python bundled with Blender.
E.g.:
import pyproj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/blender/5374/4.2/python/lib/python3.11/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj'

whereas in a standalone Python console:
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__ 
'3.6.1'

This thread is not helping much because to get a cutting-edge Blender version on Ubuntu 22.04+, it has to be installed with snap. Blender install folder is then /snap/blender/5374/4.2/ and everything in that folder is owned by root.
Also, there doesn't seem to be any pip or ensurepip executable in that folder.
Hence my question, how could I install (in the most user friendly way) a Python package which will be installed into the Python embedded with Blender (e.g. probably here: /snap/blender/5374/4.2/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/) in that specific use case?
If that may be relevant, here are the knows paths in the Blender scripting console:

import sys
for i,j in enumerate(sys.path):
    print(i,j)

0 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/scripts/startup
1 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/scripts/modules
2 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/python/lib/python311.zip
3 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/python/lib/python3.11
4 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/python/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload
5 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
6 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages
7 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/scripts/freestyle/modules
8 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/scripts/addons/modules
9 /snap/blender/5374/4.2/scripts/addons_core
10 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/scripts/addons
11 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ifcopenshell/lib/linux/64bit/python3.11
12 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ifcopenshell/express
13 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/odf
14 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/odf
15 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/odf
16 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/odf
17 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/odf
18 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/odf
19 /home/<username>/.config/blender/4.2/extensions/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/odf

(don't ask me why the last line occurs so many times...)

It's definitely a nightmare to install stuff within /snap/ directory... Even with the root user you face the message "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable". I secretly wish that Blender's dev could upgrade the blender apt package to a higher version than 3.0.x

Hello, have you explored https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules ?

Hi, thanks for the suggestion! I didn't found that post. But from what I can read, it's not about the Blender snap package and there's too much hacks to be run from inside the Python shell which I really want to avoid. Meanwhile, I decided to drop the snap package because it's too rigid and I don't want to mess with mounting points at the OS level. I'm now exploring the installation from the official tarball where I'm having some kind of hope, and my first successes.

I've had a lot of problems with modules and dependencies... I'm writing an addon to make this easier on Linux.
A little tip for this problem: (Run the following script in a text editor)
import bpy, sys, subprocess

your_module = 'pyproj==3.6.1'
dir_p = sys.executable

install = (f' -m pip install -U {your_module}')
command = (dir_p + install)

result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8')

print('FINISHED')

The last line > every time you reload a user script it adds a line to the path... It also has a solution.

