Matplotlib python import broken
In current release of Blender, 4.2.2 windows, I can no longer use matplotlib, after having sucesfully pip installed it with.
$BLENDER_PYTHON_BIN -m pip install matplotlib

When trying to import it in the scripting tab with
import matplotlib

I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
I tracked this error from the alpha release as well, when the same issue was present, except the error was then:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Matplotlib'
When I start up the embedded python interpreter, I can import and use Matplotlib without fault, so it is installed and working in the environment.
It seems that some special hack has been done when starting up the interpreter from within blender. My guess is that this is done so as to block modules that devs have found troublesome with the rest of Blender. Matplotlib and Pillow libs certainly fit in this category. I am only speculating at this point to what the reason for this error is, have found no documentation of this change from 4.1 -> 4.2.
Previously, I could easily include a large code base in my script. This code-base makes use of matplotlib, but the addon I create never uses matplotlib to create dynamic figures, or even the Agg backend to dump files on disk. There is a workaround to get Matplotlib to work perfectly fine with the existing code: namely to install also the Tornado webserver, and use the WebAgg backend. I have used this for years now without any issue on various systems/oses without fault. Now however, my large addon is broken since I cannot import matplotlib.
Since 4.2 is the LTS version, this is quite the deal-breaker for us, and I wonder if there is any workaround?
It is not possible for me to modify the large code-base with a check for every import of matplotlib, and check if it is running in blender.

Hello, are you certain the module is installed in the Blender python environment ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules
