# Mathematical formula for Bezier curves

Tags: bezier-curves

What mathematical formula does Blender use to calculate Bezier paths?

Answer (score 15):

For each segment of the path between two control points, it approximates a [cubic Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves):

[image: Bezier Curve formula]

where **P**<sub>0</sub> and **P**<sub>3</sub> are the control points and **P**<sub>1</sub> and **P**<sub>2</sub> are the handles.

[image: Visual control points]

Comment: How do you generalize this for a curve of n segments?

Answer (score 10):

Even though this isn't a question about Blender's code exactly, linking to Blender's code for calculating cubic bezier curves may help understanding.

- 2D masks can also use a different (more straightforward but slower) method where you can get any point on along the spline using a *factor*:
  See [`BKE_mask_point_segment_co`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/mask.c;7c9b1065895e0a6a12555075980d7a77d1dea8c7$492) (trivial to adapt for 3D curves too).
- 3D curves use an optimized *(less straightforward)*, fixed step, subdivision method:
  See
  [`BKE_curve_forward_diff_bezier`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/curve.c;7c9b1065895e0a6a12555075980d7a77d1dea8c7$1362)

To see how this method works, see wikipedia's description of [Higher order curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curves)

Comment: I read that bezier curves commonly are interpolated with [Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm).