# Make an object follow a complex curve?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

here I have a complex curve generated from a text,And I wan this cube to follow that curve,(making a writing animation),I tried the follow path but id didint work well,My question is:
Is there is any other way to do this?[image]

Comment: I am going to use the cube as a fluid object,so it should move,I am going to write with chocolate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As probably one of approaches is to use one cube for this animation with multiple Follow Path constraints added.

In the example below I added 5 different curves, and 5 different Follow Path constraints for the cube.

[image: gif]

I used **Offset** option (thus animated it) in all constraints except for the first one (and actually for the circle, for some reason). I also animated **Influence** option of every constraint to make every one of them to work separately.

[image]

To bake this action to keyframes and get rid of constraints you should select that cube, hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and enter Bake Action (or *3D View > Object > Animation > Bake Action*). In the options you should select **Visual Keying** and (optional) **Clear Keyframes** - you won't need them:

[image]

*based on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13532/export-animation-curve-as-values/13534#13534)*

Comment: Is there is anyway I can convert this into a key frame animation,like bake to key frame in rigid body ?

Comment: @OmarAhmad I updated my answer

Comment: It would probably be easier to duplicate that curve object (the text), and join it into one continuous curve. That way all you have to adjust is the speed/position along the curve, and you don't need to worry about constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You might be forced to use multiple curves, and a cube for each curve with a Follow Path constraint with a different Offset, and animate the cubes to appear and disappear (the camera icon on the outliner controls this) at different times.