# Let object follow joined path

Tags: animation, path

Suppose I create two paths A and B, then select both paths and join them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> creating AB. I then want a cube to follow the joined path AB, that is first along A, then jump to and follow B.

[image]

I add a "Follow Path" constraint to the cube and set keyframes for the Evaluation Time of the path. If I then animate however, the cube only follows A, as if A and B would not have been joined.

How to fix this? Obviously I could animate A and B separately but it would require more work and might get tedious if I had more paths than two and need to figure out how long each individual path is to let the cube traverse each path with the same speed.

#### Edit

Another path could look more complex like this:

[image]

Currently I model this to be four paths (one outer rectangle and three traversing straight paths) and control the cube with Keyframing the Evaluation Time and Influence properties. If I want the cube to follow the complete path (that is, all four paths) with the same speed however, I need to calculate how long each path is and model the evaluation time correctly. This is tedious...

Answer (score 4):

You can use these 2 ways to make the mesh follow path which isn't contiguous.

#### Making the path contiguous

This way assumes keyframing either the *Evaluation time* property of the curve:

[image]

or the *Fixed Position* option of the **Follow Path** constraint.

[image]

You set the keyframes so the animated mesh jumps from one curve part to another.

[image]

The mesh will now jump over the connection of the curves.

[image]

#### Adding several Follow Path Constraints

You can leave curves as they are, and add adjacent quantity of the **Follow Path** constraints, animating both *Fixed Position* and *Influence* options. 

For more details see [How to make an object follow a complex curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33916/make-an-object-follow-a-complex-curve/)

Comment: Thanks! As for option 1 I am not sure how to set the keyframes properly to make the cube jump. Also my path actually consists of an outer rectangle and a number of straight paths traversing the rectangle (I added an image to the question). Not sure how your proposal would work then.Option 2: Seems more complicated and I have not understood yet, how this would help me to animate the cube with the same speed for each path.

Comment: In case of such shapes you should either use **Follow Path** constraints as is told in the link attached, *or* create that as a mesh and add keyframes by hand, *or* break the curve in adjacent slices and make the mesh follow them apart. I added one more small [example](https://imgur.com/a/uz5Rs) for the first suggestion. It doesn't move equally; my quick and dirty solution would be to break those curves in smaller ones.